# Process for Creating and Consuming Nuget Packages

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I am currently in a situation where our team is creating a nuget package `DLL A` and consuming that package in an application `Application B`.  `A` and `B` are maintained as separate Git repositories.

Right now my process is:

1. Make changes to `A`
2. Commit and push to prerelease branch(CI is run which generates pre-release package on our Artifactory instance)
3. Nuget update `B`
4. Consume Changes in `B`

While nothing in this process takes terribly long, it does add up over time.  Previously `A` was part of the solution of `B` and we could just use project references to quickly iterate.

My question is, is there a better way to approach this process for creating and consuming Nuget packages?  I would like this to work for multiple team members who each have their development folder structure setup the way they like it. We have considered using local nuget packages, but I am unsure how to set that up so it works for everyone on the team consistently (and that still requires manually updating `B`'s nuget packages).

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 with projects that all target .net 4.6.1. Mainly I am working with Class Libraries and WPF Applications that use nuget package.config to manage nuget references.

Comment: Please provide more information about what version of VS you are using, what kind of projects are these (including TargetFrameworks and what runtime they target), and how are you managing NuGet dependencies - via packages.config file, project.json or the new PackageReference format in csproj?

Comment: @rohit21agrawal I updated the question.

Comment: Why did you switch from one repository and project references to this setup? A very good reason is that consumers of A (i.e. B) can decide when to upgrade to the next version of A independent of how A revs. Your question seems to indicate that you find this extra manual step a burden so perhaps the solution is to go back to your old setup? You cannot have it both ways.

Comment: They should have always been separate repositories. One is my application the other is utility and helper libraries that can be shared across teams/projects.

Comment: @JohnKoerner i can't think of an elegant way using packages.config approach, but is there any chance that you would be willing to migrate your projects to be project.json based? https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Converting-a-csproj-from-package.config-to-project.json